# Testing Coverage Metrics for BDD automation Testing

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, agile-testing, e2e

My manager  would like me to have a way to measure the overall amount of testing coverage that is done in a sprint.    I used to use an excel spreadsheet in the past but he doesn't want to do that.

I know that developers use KPI tools to check their unit test coverage do we have anything similar for automation testing?

Comment: What aspect of testing do you think to assess the coverage? There are a number of ways of looking into test coverage; many of which one can't "measure", but simply "assess" - https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/44995/12740

Comment: thank you for responding @JoãoFarias I honestly have never had a request like this before.  So I will read the information in the link and I will come back here If I have further questions to ask you.

Comment: Sure, additionally, probably it would be good for you to understand deeply what is your manager really look for. A metric is data, a number; people want information, a statement of the status of something. Ask him/her something like "what would like to know from this metric?" or "do feel there is some problem in the team?"